# Opening a workbook without a path

Tags: excel, vba, windows

i saw some posts related to this error, but none of them was enough to solve my problem. I was just trying to open a file( i tried with a sort of files that were in the same folder as the "vba open file", i also tried to open the files using "vba files" generated by other workbooks that were in the same folder of all these workbooks), but it doesn't happen, anytime that i did the command on immediate window or as a sub, it didn't work out and it shown the message **ERROR 1004**. I also tried to modify the name of all these files, and the folder, the location but it simply didn't work out, can someone help me? On the pics are the illustration of my problems...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code - you can include it as text and format it using the `{}` button.  If you had more code that gave you problems, then you should post that, and describe what exactly the problems were.  Most likely you should pass the full path to the Open() method - it's not good to rely on a specific value for the current directory(which is what you're doing if you just pass the filename without the path)

Comment: Is there some reason why you would want to open a workbook without the full path? If so, there is probably something you do not fully understand.

Comment: @TimWilliams sorry man, i am a novice here and didn't know the best way to post my question! And replying to the next question, the only reason that i did it, is because i saw a video where the teacher teaches to use this method to open the exact same file on the exact same folder, and in the video it works out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
workbooks.Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\myFileName.xlsl"
```

That's what I do when I want open workbooks in the same folder as the workbook using this macro.

Comment: Thanks, i am just wondering how it worked on the video that i saw, but didn't work on my file. I mean, it is the exact same syntax on both cases and i'm still looking for some help on this problem!

Comment: Can you put in a link to the video?

Comment: It's a lesson on UDEMY, one of those first lessons that introduce some of the content of vba. And on the lesson, the teacher said that this is a way to open the file, in his case workout, but due maybe to this issue with the fullpath, i was unable to do the same...